# Changing from 8 channel to 16 channel. Does change in voltage input affect upgrade?

Tags: gpio, ttl

I am going from a Numato 8 channel GPIO to a Numato 16 channel GPIO. The 8 channel I/O pins support 5V TTL signals but the 16 channel I/O pins support 3.3V TTL signals.

If the input to the I/O of the 16 channel GPIO is going to be 3.6V - 4.0V, will that be too high of a voltage to be able to use the 16 channel GPIO?

I posted this question on the Numato forum and put in a help ticket with Numato technical support but haven't received an answer.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Without a good spec, like Iih max =5mA at 3.5V or a clamp diode PN spec and series R value, it is unknown except GPIO input high voltage= 3.3V If unknown then you can add 0.5V/5mA= 100 Ohm in series to limit the voltage/current with the internal ESD diodes at 0.2V

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the gpio are not 5V tolerant at 3.3V, then 4V will likely cause problems and may fry a port. If these are just inputs, a resistor voltage divider would work. If they are current carrying, a silicon diode in series can help.